# Display String in Windows Forms Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, console

I have a string named " **e.RequestMessage.Text** " . In a class this string I want to show has a value int a textbox in a windows form .

I have the project that contains a class which shows my string in a console. So I want to show this sting in a textbox on a windows form. I added a windows form to it (the class runs in front)

How can I accomplish this?

```
using System;
using Eneter.Messaging.DataProcessing.Serializing;
using Eneter.Messaging.EndPoints.TypedMessages;
using Eneter.Messaging.MessagingSystems.MessagingSystemBase;
using Eneter.Messaging.MessagingSystems.TcpMessagingSystem;
using Eneter.ProtoBuf;
using message.declarations;

namespace ServiceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IDuplexTypedMessageReceiver<MyResponse, MyRequest> myReceiver;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiate Protocol Buffer based serializer.
            ISerializer aSerializer = new ProtoBufSerializer();

            // Create message receiver receiving 'MyRequest' and receiving 'MyResponse'.
            // The receiver will use Protocol Buffers to serialize/deserialize messages. 
            IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aReceiverFactory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory(aSerializer);
            myReceiver = aReceiverFactory.CreateDuplexTypedMessageReceiver<MyResponse, MyRequest>();

            // Subscribe to handle messages.
            myReceiver.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;

            // Create TCP messaging.
            IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();

            IDuplexInputChannel anInputChannel
                = aMessaging.CreateDuplexInputChannel("tcp://127.0.0.1:8060/");

            // Attach the input channel and start to listen to messages.
            myReceiver.AttachDuplexInputChannel(anInputChannel);

            Console.WriteLine("The service is running. To stop press enter.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Detach the input channel and stop listening.
            // It releases the thread listening to messages.
            myReceiver.DetachDuplexInputChannel();
        }

        // It is called when a message is received.
        private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, TypedRequestReceivedEventArgs<MyRequest> e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + **e.RequestMessage.Text**);

            // Create the response message.
            MyResponse aResponse = new MyResponse();
            aResponse.Length = e.RequestMessage.Text.Length;

            // Send the response message back to the client.
            myReceiver.SendResponseMessage(e.ResponseReceiverId, aResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

**Windows form code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ServiceExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to really narrow it down.  I follow that you want to display a string somewhere.  Beyond that, what you are trying to display, where, and what isn't working as expected is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sum = x + y;
        MessageBox.Show("Ans=" + sum);
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myString = sum.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = myString;
    }
```

Comment: i want to convert sum into string and than show in messagebox3

Answer (score 0):

Where do you construct the form?

One thing you can do is create a custom constructor for the form that takes in a `String` and just pass `e.RequestMessage.Text` to it.

Something like:

```
public Form1(String messageText)
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    aTextBox.Text = messageText;
}
```

And then in `ServiceExample`:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1(e.RequestMessage.Text);
```

Comment: thanks man thats what i want to do , i still don't know how to run the  window form in the front and the ServiceExample at the background and update my value in the windows  form  automatically sorry for my  english thanks

Comment: What you can do is create a method `setTextBoxText(string whatever){ aTextBox.Text = whatever;}` and then construct the `Form` at the beginning of your main method in `ServiceExample`. Then, when you receive the message, to set the text call `setTextBoxText(e.RequestMessage.Text)`.

Comment: in the main method in serviceexample i added new System.Threading.Thread(() => { System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1()); }).Start();  as a result my windows form runs and in the OnMessageReceived method i added Form1 form1 = new Form1(e.RequestMessage.Text); also in form class  public Form1(String messageText)
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    aTextBox.Text = messageText;
}   but i still cant show any values of my string , tgo make sure did Form1 OnMessageReceived = new Form1("working yep yep "); but nothing show up thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update the value of your textbox as part of the event?  This would be accomplished as:

```
    public void OnMessageReceived(params)
    {
        yourTextBox.Text = e.RequestMessage.Text;
    }
```

Unless I misunderstood your question, this should do what you expect.

Comment: OnMessageReceived is a metggghod in another class thanks